# How to get loading gif when an html element is empty and remove when is not empty?

Tags: jquery, ajax, loading

I have a very simple search, and I would like that when I search, while loading, to get a loading image.

```
<div id="search-filters">
    <button class="search">Search</button>
</div>
<div id="loading"></div>
<div id="results"></div>
```

I treid to get the loading image when i click on `#search` button only if `div#result`s is empty, and then when div#results has some contents hide `#loading`.

That is what i did:

```
       $("#search").click(function() {
            if($.trim($("#results").html())=='') {
                $('#loading').show();
            }
            else if ($('#results:not(:empty)').length) {    
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        });
```

But the problem is that after i get the result the #loading doesn't `.hide()`, why?
Where I went wrong?
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Could you post an example on [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: can't you just show the loading gif on button click and remove it after the ajax call is completed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing ajax or something similar is used for the search, and you have to wait for that to finish :

```
$("#search").on('click', function() {
    $('#loading').toggle( $("#results").is(':empty') );

    $.ajax({
        url : 'search.php', 
        data: this.value
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#results').html(data);
    }).always(function() {
        $('#loading').hide();
        if ( $("#results").is(':empty') ) $('#results').html('No results !');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `else if` condition

try this -

```
$("#search").click(function() {
            if($.trim($("#results").html())=='') {
                $('#loading').show();
            }
            else{    
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
});
```

Comment: I treid but the #loading remains visible.